# How to assign value in $(document).ready from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i'm developing a .net application using twitter bootstrap.

I'm trying to get data from .aspx.cs page to .aspx page.

Please find my code below:

**strOblect.cs**

```
public class strObject
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**.aspx.cs page:**

```
public List<strObject> stringList = new List<strObject>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   strObject ObjOne=new strObject();
   ObjOne.Name="One";
   ObjOne.Description ="One";
   stringList.Add(ObjOne);
   strObject ObjTwo=new strObject();
   ObjTwo.Name="Two";
   ObjTwo.Description ="Two";
   stringList.Add(ObjTwo);
   strObject ObjThree=new strObject();
   ObjThree.Name="Three";
   ObjThree.Description ="Three";
   stringList.Add(ObjThree);
}
```

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:Panel  ID="pnlData"  runat="server" style="background-color:White;">

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
    var valueAssigned=stringList;
});

</script>

</asp:Panel>
```

I'm **unable to get stringList value in $(document).ready**.

Please help me out to get the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your `stringList` is actually a collection of objects. In order to use it in JavaScript as such, you'll need to serialize it to a javascript object.

```
var valueAssigned=<%=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(stringList)%>;
```

So that you can wind up with the following:

```
var valueAssigned= [{Name: "Foo", Description: "Bar"}, {...}];
```

**Edit**

`JavaScriptSerializer` is in `System.Web.Script.Serialization` - you'll either need to add this below at the top of your `<%@ Page`

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
```

or specify the FQ name

```
var valueAssigned=<%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
                         .Serialize(stringList)%>;
```

Comment: I got the error:  **An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.** when i use var valueAssigned=<%=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(stringList);%>;

Comment: Scuse the delay - you'll need to qualify the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

StuartLC's answer will be enough.JSON is very good option for that purpose. Other option can be to register client script in aspx.cs. Here is another SO question regarding that

[How do I pass data from c# to jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986041/how-do-i-pass-data-from-c-sharp-to-jquery-javascript)